# How do I change this query on the date to display in a format other than mysql typical

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following echo from a result of a query (to display when the product was purchased) but would prefer to have it display, instead of ***2013-01-30*** to simply ***0130***.

How do I recode this to produce the desired result?

**Note:**  This is just one line of echoed results; so, I'd prefer not to alter the mysql query itself.

```
echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($row['bookdate'])),'</u>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take the appropriate parts of your date:

```
$parts = explode('-', $row['bookdate']);
echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($parts[1] . $parts[2])),'</u>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATE_FORMAT` when selecting the date:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(bookdate, '%m%d') AS myDate ...
```

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)